# $L/K$ is galois extension if only if for arbitrary field homomorphism $ \sigma $: $L→\Bbb{C}$, $\sigma (L)⊂L$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a subfield of $ \Bbb{C}$. $L/K$ be a field extension.

Then, $L/K$ is galois extension if only if for arbitrary field homomorphism which fixes $K$, $ \sigma $: $L→\Bbb{C}$, $\sigma (L)⊂L$ ?

If $L/K$ is galois(Here I define galois extension as separable and normal extension), obviously $σ(L)⊂L$, but I don't have confident the whether the converse holds.

Comment: Can you add your "obvious" proof for $L/K$ Galois, e.g., for $L/K=\overline{\Bbb Q}/\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Take arbitrary $α\in L$, and $α$'s minimai polynomial over $K$ be $f$. Then $σ(α)$ is also root of $f$, so from $L/K$ galois, $σ(α)$ is in $L$.

Comment: Which of the (equivalent) definitions of "normal" are you working with?

Comment: For arbitrary element of $L$, its conjugate lies again in $L$.

Comment: Then I would try to prove that the restriction to $L$ of the conjugation homomorphism fixes $K$ and use the hypothesis. But note that it will fix $K$ is and only if $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: For the claim to be true you need to assume that $L\subset \Bbb{C}$ (in addition to $L/K$ being Galois). Otherwise you have problems like the following: $K=\Bbb{Q}$, $L=K[x]/\langle x^2-2\rangle$, where $L$ is not a subset of $\Bbb{C}$, and we have a $K$-morphism $\sigma$ mapping the coset of $x$ to $\sqrt2\notin L$.